# Songs with off-beats?

Tags: terminology, rhythm

I found this a lot in old songs, but also in quite a few new ones. I love songs that have this, off-beat music playing in the background. I know the song 'Bernadette' by IAMX has it. The beginning of Green Day's 'Viva la Gloria' has it. So does Caro Emerald's 'That Man.' I absolutely adore this so I was wondering:

Does anyone know what this is called in music other than "off-beat" or "syncopation?"

Comment: You may be referring to a "back beat", a strong pulse on beats 2 and 4 in 4/4 time (for example).

Answer (score 1):

The IAMX example is pretty much [oom-pah bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oom-pah), which typically goes   [root - chord - 5th - chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oom-pah#/media/File:Oom-pah.png).  The downbeats are strong single notes (from the tuba in a brass band), usually alternating between the root and the fifth of the current chord, and the offbeats are chords (played by the higher pitched horns in a brass band).  This puts a kind of emphasis on the off beats since the higher pitched, thicker chords appear on it.

In terms of piano technique, this is  [stride piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_%28music%29), as exemplified in your Caro Emerald example.  This term is more closely associated with jazz styles.

Comment: I'd embed the wikimedia image that shows the notation for oom-pah bass, but the imagur engine that we use doesn't accept png images.